# Resizing div after iframe change src

Tags: php, html, iframe, resize, onclick

So I automatically resize my iframe based on content height as follows:

```
<iframe name="main" id="main" src="main.php" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" onload="this.style.height = main.document.body.scrollHeight + 5; this.style.width = main.document.body.scrollWidth">
```

However, I also use a link to change the src (utilizing target if anyone was wondering), but my iframes vary heights vastly, and after changing back to the shorter one, my methods of resizing the div/document body haven't worked...

ex.

```
<a href="mail.php" onclick="document.getElementById("content").style.height = main.document.body.scrollHeight" target="main">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try onclick="document.getElementById(\"content\").style...

Comment: or document.getElementById('content')

Answer (score -1):

Div resize was working fine, provided I fix the double quotes...the problem was that the iframe wasn't resizing after changing source, got it working now though...Thanks

Comment: For future reference, it would be a good idea to post exactly how you got it working..